# ANSYS - transformer issue (Convergence not achieved)

Tags: power-electronics, simulation

Whole day i am trying to simulate this converter to get current for transformer windings which will be than used for simulation (core + copper losses).
But i am just not able to get this working. I was trying to change settings of transient simulation according to twinbuilder built in documentation, but no results were achieved.
EDIT: I though issue are diodes, but i have figure out that there is need for Mutual inductance between secondary windings in this case "M3".
[image]

Comment: Given how much ANSYS costs, you should really contact their support first :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using different solver settings. Put in series resistance across all inductors and switches (estimate wire resistance and put it in the simulation). Also you probably need to put in a real diode model instead of the default one.